Private Channels not working in Filament project
I have a filament (laravel) project. I'm using filament for whole application. Authentication, roles, permissions everything is handled through filament.
In a filament custom page, I need to use Laravel reverb for real time updates without reloading page.
For it's setup, I followed the official docs of laravel reverb.
But on client side, I have not used the echo.js generated by php artisan install:broadcasting, instead used
config/filament.php:
    ...
    'broadcasting' => [
    
            'echo' => [
                'broadcaster' => 'reverb',
                'key' => env('VITE_REVERB_APP_KEY'),
                'cluster' => env('VITE_REVERB_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'wsHost' => env('VITE_REVERB_HOST'),
                'wsPort' => env('VITE_REVERB_PORT', 80),
                'wssPort' => env('VITE_REVERB_PORT', 443),
                'authEndpoint' => '/broadcasting/auth',
                'disableStats' => true,
                'encrypted' => true,
                'forceTLS' => env('VITE_REVERB_SCHEME', 'https') === 'https',
            ],
    
        ],
    ...

Also added Broadcast::routes(['middleware' => [Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class]]); to boot method of AppServiceProvider.php, because without this I was getting 404 not found error on '/broadcasting/auth'.
Now public channels are working without any issue but private channels are not working.
Below is the code of Event NewGroupMessage.php
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\GroupMessage;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class NewGroupMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(public GroupMessage $message)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel('new-group-message.' . $this->message->group_id),
            new Channel('new-group-message'),
        ];
    }

    public function broadcastWith()
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->message->id,
            'created_by_id' => $this->message->created_by_id,
            'message' => $this->message->message,
            'created_at' => $this->message->created_at,
        ];
    }
}

channels.php
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast;

Broadcast::channel('App.Models.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int) $user->id === (int) $id;
});

Broadcast::channel('new-group-message.{groupId}', function ($user, $groupId) {
    return true;
});

In blade file:
<script>
        function getMessages() {
            window.Echo.private('new-group-message.{{ $groupId }}')
                .listen('NewGroupMessage', (e) => {
                    console.log('new group message private ');
                    console.log(e);
                })
            window.Echo.channel('new-group-message')
                .listen('NewGroupMessage', (e) => {
                    console.log('new group message public ');
                    console.log(e);
                })


        }

        window.addEventListener('load', getMessages);
    </script>

Here public channel works fine but private channel doesn't even subscribe to channel.

Please help, what I'm missing?
I'm using:
Laravel: 11.18.1
Filament: 3.2
Reverb: 1.0
Laravel Echo: 1.16.1


After trying so many things and reading official docs of Laravel Broadcasting, Laravel Reverb, and Filament, it is now working. Sharing the solution below for other developers facing similar issue:
Either add following lines of code to boot method of
AppServiceProvider.php:
        // other code if any

        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Broadcast::routes([
            'middleware' => [
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            ]
        ]);
        require base_path('routes/channels.php');


Or add following lines of code to bootstrap/app.php:
    ->withBroadcasting(
        __DIR__ . '/../routes/channels.php',
        [
            'middleware' => [
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            ]
        ],
    )

Final bootstrap\app.php will look like this:
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )
    ->withBroadcasting(
        __DIR__ . '/../routes/channels.php',
        [
            'middleware' => [
                \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
                \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
                \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
                \Filament\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
            ]
        ],
    )
    ->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        //
    })
    ->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

NOTE: Add above code in one file only. Either in AppServiceProvider or bootstrap\app.php.
